# Autofit column in ClosedXML.Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, xls, closedxml

I understand that the question stupid and from FAQ, but i cant set auto width in excel columns (using ClosedXML.Excel library)

my code:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var wsDep = wb.Worksheets.Add("MyWorksheet");
wsDep.Columns("A").AdjustToContents();
wsDep.Columns("B1").AdjustToContents();
wsDep.Columns().AdjustToContents();
```

but nothing changes. 
how can i set auto width columns with ClosedXML.Excel library??

Comment: @FrancoisBotha - maybe make that an answer, it might be accepted.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your cells don't have any contents. Therefore `AdjustToContents()` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 31):

```
wsDep.Columns().AdjustToContents();
```

You should write this code at the end of your code section because it's working only when you write it at the end of your code.

Answer (score 12):

You need to give the range of the columns.
**Example:**
`wsDep.Columns("A","H").AdjustToContents();`

Answer (score 4):

Adding to an old post in case someone comes across this one like I did. My fix was to use the `worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();` but I had to add it after I wrote out all of the data. Initially I was setting it when I was setting up all of my column headers and colors during up creation of the worksheet and it wasn't working. I then came across this thread and it made me think that it was adjusting the contents at the point that I was calling the AdjustToContents which in my case have anything more than the column headers at that point. I moved it to the end after writing out all of my data and it worked as expected and actually makes sense as to what it was doing.

Answer (score 2):

try below code.

```
foreach (var item in worksheet.ColumnsUsed())
{
    item.AdjustToContents();
}
```